# Change background and textcolor in cardview on touch

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having difficulty in changing the text color with the background color on touch (hover effect) in cardview. I have changed the background color but not the text color.

I have also tried to use selector but i didn't worked out.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

It changes the color of the text and its background

[image]

My layout

[image]

on pressing I want to change the color text with the background

[image]

Here is my LayoutCode

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f1f1f3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/listhover">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cardviewimage_cio" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Use on touch listener. Example:

```
cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                return true;
            } else {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

---

Use a selector as a background for CardView.

bg_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Add it like this:

```
    android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
```

Comment: it makes the text and the background of the text into black...I want just the text to change the color